# GitHub Client Secret key should remain secret?

Tags: github

I'm writing an open source github client (c++/qt). First step is obviously authentication.

Since it isn't a web app I can't use the "web-flow" but basic authentication+authorization that exposes to the public also the client secret. I looked for a solution in other applications: I found that choqok, a KDE Micro-Blogging Client, stores in source code twitter's consumer key and secret, so this practice isn't completely evil.

Can I do the same for github client secret key?

Very thanks

Comment: The problem with the approach is that any user of your app may impersonate you as far as the GitHub API is concerned. (E.g. exhaust your API call quota.) Since they can do that through regular use of your app anyway, there's not much to be done besides require the users to get their own API keys.